# Delete view by identifier in android

Tags: android

How exactly can I remove elements in android by an identifier? For example, if I have a `layout vertical` which contains several buttons, how can I put something like a tag to that buttons so that I can erase them dinamically after?

Comment: What's wrong with `removeView()`?

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag:

```
view.setTag(yourTag)
```

Remove the view with that tag:

```
layout.removeView(layout.findViewWithTag(yourTag))
```

Comment: how can I change this tag after by having the view?

Comment: You can change it any time with `setTag`, even when it is already in the layout.

Comment: but will that add another tag or will it *replace* it?

Comment: Replace. A rule of thumb: if it says `set…`, it replaces a value, it would say `add…` if it adds another value.